# Google Guava Function for extracting a key from Map.Entry

Tags: java, casting

I would like to have a something like this (Java):

```
class MapEntries {

    private static final Function<Map.Entry<Object, Object>, Object> EXTRACT_KEY =
        new Function<Map.Entry<Object, Object>, Object>() {
          @Override
          public Object apply(Map.Entry<Object, Object> input) {
              return input.getKey();
          }
    }

    public static <K, V> Function<Map.Entry<K, V>, K> extractKey() {
        return EXTRACT_KEY;
    }
}
```

Note that `EXTRACT_KEY` is a singleton, and `extractKey()` uses generics for type safety.

Unfortunately, javac complains about illegal cast when I write `return EXTRACT_KEY;`. I tried many variants but nothing seems to work. There must be a way to do this. Anyone?

**edit:**

I forgot to mention that somewhere else in the code I would like to do:

```
void foo(Iterable<? extends Entry<K, V>> entries) {                
    Iterable<T> keys = Iterables.<Entry<K, V>, K>transform(entries,
                             MapEntries.extractKey());
    // more code follows...
}
```

Using the `(Function) EXTRACT_KEY` cast solved the compilation error in MapEntries. However javac still complains about foo():

> The parameterized method `<Map.Entry<K,V>, T>transform(Iterable<Map.Entry<K,V>>, Function<? super Map.Entry<K,V>,? extends K>) of type Iterables is not applicable for the arguments (Iterable<capture#13-of ? extends Map.Entry<K,V>>,`Function,Object>)

Comment: For that second case, you have to use `MapEntries.<K, V>extractKey()`.

Answer (score 2):

You must either stop treating `EXTRACT_KEY` as a singleton -- allocating a new `Function` each time -- or accept the need for an unsafe cast, which can by done with `return (Function) EXTRACT_KEY`.

Comment: The unsafe cast cf. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html#3151